# OBS (Open Broadcaster Software): захват окна с меняющимся названием

Tags: linux, потоки-данных, obs

OBS (Open Broadcaster Software) позволяет захватить окно, для этого нужно выбрать его название из выпадающего списка. Однако если название окна меняется, OBS его теряет и начинает показывать другое окно. Хочется, чтобы даже после изменения названия OBS понимала, что окно никуда не пропало и продолжала его захватывать.

Поискал по настройкам и в гугле, кажется, ответов не нашёл.

Нужно это, как можно понять из картинки, чтобы стримить окно браузера. При переходе, например, на другую вкладку, название свего окна меняется.

[image: вот так можно выбрать окно, но когда меняешь вкладку в браузере, название окна меняется]

Comment: obs — многозначная аббревиатура. уточните, пожалуйста, в тексте вопроса (нажав [edit]), что именно вы под ней подразумеваете.